# URI::InvalidURIError when performing Feature Tests in RSpec Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, automated-tests, uri, capybara

I am currently developing feature tests for a Ruby on Rails website in Capybara and every time I attempt to run this test file, I am greeted with the same error.
I have listed the code below for the test and the error received is just below the code and is shortened only to main events.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Home features' do
    it 'displays company name' do
        visit "/login"
        expect(page).to have_content("Company Name Here")
    end
end
```

```
  1) Home features displays company name
     Failure/Error: visit "/login"
     
     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): nil
     # /home/linuxuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:76:in `build_uri'
     ...
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NoMethodError:
     #   undefined method `to_str' for nil:NilClass
     ...
     #   /home/linuxuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:76:in `build_uri'
```

I have of course attempted to debug this myself prior and given it was a URI issue and I specified the URI gem I originally thought it was a gem conflict which was disproved when I removed it from the Gemfile and performed a bundle install.

Afterwards I then tested variations of the visit url including single and double quotations as well as also trying manual uris such as [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) which ended up in a separate get error, however the error occurred prior to the uri error, so I assumed that was not related.

Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated thank you.

=============Update=============
Here is a snippet from the config/routes.rb

```
  match "/login", to: "sessions#new", via: [:get]
  match "/login", to: "sessions#create", via: [:post]
```

===Further Update ======
Added StackTrace

````
FF

Failures:

  1) Home features displays company name
     Failure/Error: visit "/login"
     
     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): nil
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:76:in `build_uri'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:68:in `process'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:56:in `block in process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:51:in `times'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:51:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:24:in `visit'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:46:in `visit'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:278:in `visit'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:53:in `call'
     # /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:53:in `visit'
     # ./spec/features/home_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # NoMethodError:
     #   undefined method `to_str' for nil:NilClass
     #   /home/aus3r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/gems/capybara-3.36.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:76:in `build_uri'
    ```
````

Comment: Wondering if maybe your server is issuing a redirect with a `nil` path or something?  Capy is trying to follow it and bombing out.

Comment: Hi, I don't if that maybe the issue as the site has obviously been working during development, and I've updated the question to show the routes for the login page. 
Which shows everything to be in order, so I don't really know why it would be nil.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to debug in a `feature` spec. Try adding the following line to your spec and see if there's a redirect happening: `specify(nil, type: :request) { get '/login'; expect(response).to redirect_to '' }`

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell Show more of the stack trace so we can tell where the call to build_uri is initially coming from, shouldn't be possible for that to be `nil`

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I just added more of the stack trace

Comment: @SebastianSouthwell From following that stacktrace this error means that `last_response['Location']` is returning nil when attempting to redirect - That means your app somehow isn't doing a redirect correctly (or maybe you're using a really old version of rack/rack-test) .  Check your test.log and see what your app is doing in response to the initial unauthenticated get request to /login

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you're not skipping authentication for your login endpoint, and so it's (trying) to redirect to itself, which is bombing out somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving external support, I realised this was an issue with legacy code and the https://github.com/biola/rack-cas (rack-cas gem), and needed this addition into the config/application.rb

```
    config.rack_cas.exclude_paths = "/"
```

Apparently the site was trying to perform CAS authentication due to existing legacy code which is similar to the responses provided by @ThomasWalpole and @smathy as they mentioned that the request was unauthenticated.